# Плавная замена блоков

Tags: jquery

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать, чтоб при нажатии кнопку, один `div` блок плавно заменялся другим и как это реализовать на `jQuery`?

Comment: так же как [здесь](щас найду.. на hashcode) картинки

Comment: сорри, здесь http://hashcode.ru/questions/248858#248864

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[[@eicto](/users/11304/eicto)](/users/11304/eicto), по вашей ссылке

> Страница не найдена

Можно сделать, например так: http://jsfiddle.net/alpha9000/f54MG/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/f54MG/1/

Comment: как бы toggle подразумевает 2 блока (first и last), да и топик стартеру нужно "подменить один див другим", ну а так согласен что с 3мя не работает