# Замена блока (div) на другой

Tags: jquery, html

Скажите, как можно сделать, чтобы развернутый блок сворачивался полностью, а вместо его выезжал другой, с нужной мне информацией. И это все по нажатию на ссылку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрите тут: [Плавная замена блоков](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/249646/jquery-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Если принципиально нужна анимация "сворачивания", `fadeToggle` замените на `toggle`